# Improve input audio signals to car audio system

Tags: signal-processing, dac, ohms-law

I am helping a friend to solve a low and not so clear sound to his car's audiosystem, when using aux-input in particular. He is getting great signals from CD or Radio, but when he feeds the audiosystem with analog in, it sounds "okay" but low. I have tried different quality cables and signal medias such as mp3, flac, WAV and streaming from youtube. Even with high quality cables and high resolution media files like flac, it did not sound as good as CD. I even tried with different phones, but still not satisfied.

And then I suddenly thought of this idea: "What if we transmit the data from the phone to a DAC (with a mini amp inside) and then further to the car's audiosystem." Would not that be awesome? I understand it is not easy to imagine how it will sound untill you try it. Therefore I drew couple of sketches on how to approach to a solution to the problem and also how to supply the DAC and the phone with power while the phone and the DAC exchanges data. All those three components interacting simultaneously. The third component here is a node (power source) from the car which is then transformed with a buck converter from 12V to 5V. Transformer can supply MAX 15 W power. That means it can supply max 3A current, from P = UI formula.

On second sketch I wonder if it would be necessary with a fuse or resistor next to the phone and the dac (in series with each of those to components, just like pointed on the sketch).

According to a article at digitalaudioreview, the DAC is supposed to drain 4-5mA. Let us say i want to allow it to get max 10mA. R = U/I = 5V / 10mA = 500Ω and the phone to charge at max 1A. R = 5V / 1A = 5Ω

My last question is would it be necessary with a resistor or a maybe a fuse or will those components drain as much as they need so I can expect it to go fine? What else would to do or not do to make this idea easier and realizable?

[image: Diagram from audio signal perspective]

[image: Diagram from power supply perspective]

Comment: Wouldn't a bit more gain on the analog input be much simpler?

Comment: "_Would not that be awesome?_" Probably not. You have a lot of work to do. You will have to get the audio out on USB, decode it, split it into two stereo channels, filter these and probably wind up with worse audio quality than analog. An awful lot of trouble. As Brian suggests, just amplify the analog. Before you do any of that read the audio system manual and see if there is an AUX input gain adjust that will solve the problem completely without any modifications.

Comment: I thought all Aux inputs expect 1Vrms or almost 3Vpp which should be possible on external headphones.  If you can design Y you should be able to measure X the actual output.

Comment: The other problem with Andriod/smartphones is they auto 'correct' the volume all the time from the headphone output. I think if you look at the audio settings on the phone and put it all the way to maximum volume you will have a much better signal to the car stereo. The trouble is Android will reset the volume again when you unplug the headphone then give you warning about loud volumes. sigh..

Comment: Why complicate things by introducing DAC into system. It will only further worsen the system. Instead try increasing the gain of the auxiliary input or make use of an intermediate amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any resistors.  If provided with the correct voltage, an appliance will draw as much current as it needs.  So long as the power supply can supply that current, all is good.

As for fuses, you'd have to check your power supply.  Many have built-in over-current protection, and will simply shut down if the output is shorted.  If yours doesn't, then an appropriately rated quick-blow fuse would be a good idea.  But you'd only need one, to protect the power supply.